# Django: http_permissions interfering with tests

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a view that list records. If I'm already login, I can access it with no problems. If have not login yet and try to access the page, I get redirected to the login page. So far so good!

But during my tests I have the following issue: I am able to successfully login, but when I try to execute a get to list the records, I get a 403 (Permission denied) and a 302 (redirect, likely to login page). I don't understand what is going on. I know http_permissions is interfering with the tests, as I have commented the http_permissions and the test passed. Do I have to grant this http_permissions to the test user? Anyone can cast some light on this? Here is my code:

**teleconsultoria/models.py**

```
...
class Bibliografia(BaseModel):
    ativa = models.BooleanField(u'Ativa', default=True)
    link = models.CharField(u'Link', blank=True, max_length=2000,)
    nome = models.CharField(u'Nome', blank=False, max_length=255,)
    arquivo = SizeRestrictedFileField(
        u'PDF da Bibliografia', upload_to='bibliografia', blank=True, null=True,
    )   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Bibliografia'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Bibliografias'
        permissions = ( 
            ('ver_bibliografia', u'Pode ver bibliografia'),
            ('criar_bibliografia', u'Pode criar bibliografia'),
            ('alterar_bibliografia', u'Pode alterar bibliografia'),
            ('excluir_bibliografia', u'Pode excluir bibliografia'),
        )
...
```

**teleconsultoria/views.py**

```
...
class BibliografiaListView(ModelListView):                                                                    
    model = Bibliografia                                                                                      
    app_name = 'teleconsultoria'                                                                              
    table = BibliografiaTable                                                                                 
    search_fields = ('id', 'ativa', 'nome', 'link')                                                           
    http_permissions = ('teleconsultoria.ver_bibliografia',)                                                  

    def get_queryset(self, request):                                                                          
        return self.model.objects.order_by('id')                                                              

...
```

**teleconsultoria/tests.py**

```
def test_ver_lista_bibliografias_se_existirem_bibliografias(self):
    Bibliografia.objects.create(**{'nome': 'Bibliografia 1'})
    Bibliografia.objects.create(**{'nome': 'Bibliografia 2'})
    Bibliografia.objects.create(**{'nome': 'Bibliografia 3'})
    response = self.client.get('/teleconsultoria/bibliografia/')
    self.assertIn('3 Bibliografias', response.content)
```

> AssertionError: '3 Bibliografias' not found in ''

Comment: Where is your login handeld? A Webserver infront of Django or directly in django? What kind of login are we talking? Basic Auth?

Comment: Directly in django. Auth is made using a custom url. In tests we use it like this: `self.client.post('/accounts/login/?next=/', data=data, follow=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! By going through the Django docs, I found I could manually add the necessary permissions:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

My main Test Case ended up like this:

```
class BibliografiaCrudTestCase(BaseFluxoTestCase):                                                            

    dados = {}                                                                                                
    permissions = ['ver_bibliografia', 'criar_bibliografia', 'alterar_bibliografia', 'excluir_bibliografia']  

    def setUp(self):                                                                                          
        super(BibliografiaCrudTestCase, self).setUp()                                                         
        self.login()                                                                                          
        usuario = Usuario.objects.first()                                                                     
        for permission in Permission.objects.filter(codename__in=self.permissions):                           
            usuario.user_permissions.add(permission.id)
    ...
```